# How does smyfony know which entity to use from the form

Tags: symfony

Okay here is an example.

I have set up a project for testing.
Now i have a 
`DatabaseInteractionType.php` Class.

Where i have this field.

```
           ->add(
                'question',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter your Question',
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    ],
                    'required' => true
                ]
            )
```

`question`  is take from my Enitity Which is Called 
`DatabaseInteraction.php`

Now Lets say i want to replace `question` with another field from another Entitiy. 
Where is thate defined ?

Backround for asking: I used make:form to create a form based on the Enitity. But now i want to know where the 'connection' is made.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly [PropertyAccess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) magic. If you have a field `question` (the first parameter of the `FormBuilder::add()` call) in your form, it will be used to look on your given Entity or array, if it has a field/property/key that has a similar name. Similar in this context means: (for objects) a method called `getQuestion`, a method called `isQuestion` or `hasQuestion`, a property or method called `question`, if the object has the magic `__get` or `__call` defined, it will use that too. (all those of course only, if public). These are - I believe - most of the options that are used to somehow resolve the property access. (Details can be found on the [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) provided at the start of the paragraph.)

Now, the form types all have an option [`property_path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path), with which you can set a different property to look for (where you can even go into the depth, see also [PropertyAccess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) for more details).

So that "connection" is made from Symfony's Form component utilizing Symfony's PropertyAccess component. On the other hand, the `make:form` cli command uses [reflection](https://www.php.net/reflection) to look up which fields are accessible on the selected entity.

Answer (score 0):

the data_class option is the way to get the name of the class in form.

> the data_class option by adding the following to your form type class

like that:

```html
// src/Form/TaskType.php
use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

// ...
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Task::class,
    ]);
}
```